# React input type=“number” for floats - HTML standard?

Tags: html, reactjs

Having a sample React component for testing input type behavior.

Initially the input type is set to 'text' and it's value is initialized with '1.0'.
Clicking the button the value will be converted to Number. The value displayed on the input box now shows '1' - Ok.

Setting the input type to 'number' and clicking the button, the value displayed on the input box will stay at '1.0' - is this supposed to work so, i mean is this so specified by html standard ? Same behavior on chrome/firefox/iexplorer (for firefox the value '1.0' has to be entered again, as it will show '1' on type change to 'number').

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.defVal = '1.0';

        this.state = {
            val: this.defVal,
            type: 'text'
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeType = this.onChangeType.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            val: e.target.value
        });
    }
    
    onChangeType(e) {
        this.setState({
            val: this.defVal,
            type: e.target.value
        });
    }    

    onClick(e) {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
          val: Number(this.state.val)
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return <div id='flex-container'>
            <input type={this.state.type} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.val} step="any" />
            <label className='state-val'>state.val: {this.state.val}</label>
            <select value={this.state.type} onChange={this.onChangeType}>
              <option value="text">Text</option>
              <option value="number">Number</option>
            </select>
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>Convert to Number</button>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 150px;
}

#flex-container > * {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.state-val {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's standard behavior. The value of `<input type="number">` is specified as valid floating-point number (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)), which supports not only fractional part but also exponential form like `1.9E2`